# Changing JSON transformation to XML in neoload

Tags: xml, json, neoload

Given the following HTTP response :

```
{"id":"1", "name":test"}
```

At the moment, when you check "see JSON requests/responses as xml content" in "Edition > Preferences > Project settings > Modules Manager > JSON" (in order to be able to use xpath instead of regexp), you have a completely useless stuff like :

```
<ObjectNode>
  <__children>
    <entry>
      <string>id</string>
      <__value>1</__value>
    </entry>
      etc...
```

Note : this is useless because when you have deep JSON response, you have XPath like :
    ArrayNode/__children/child::ObjectNode/__children/entry[child::string/text()='data']/ObjectNode/__children/entry[child::string/text()='id']/IntNode/__value

I have managed to create an extension where I parse the JSON inside a JSONObject or JSONArray and then I call

```
return "<root>"+XML.toString(json)+"</root>";
```

which gives me a beautifull

```
<root><id>1</id><name>test</name></root>
```

Note : that I could process easily with xpath

The problem is that then Neoload converts this to

```
<String>&lt;root&gt;&lt;id&gt;etc...
```

which is as useless as the first stuff (maybe more useless because XPath is not an option anymore as I only have one node).

So my question is how can I change the way Neoload is transforming my Decoder return value ?

I have tried to return JSONObject or JSONArray in the Decoder directly and then to use a Namer, but the Namer seems to be used only with requests, not with responses.

Any hint is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easier" way I found to simulate real JSON is to do the following.

First, do a normal web page call and add a variable via the advanced panel to capture all the response (the regexp to use is (.*)).

Then, use a javascript with the following content (here, EntryResponse is the captured variable name)

```
//get the previous http response and eval it
var resp_ = context.variableManager.getValue("EntryResponse");
if (resp_ == null) {
        context.fail("Variable 'EntryResponse' not found");
}
logger.debug("EntryResponse="+resp_);
var resp = eval("("+resp_+")")

//then used resp as real json
logger.debug("Logged User Id="+resp.data.id);

// Inject a value in a runtime variable
context.variableManager.setValue("UserName", resp.data.id);
```

This is not as straightforward as it could be but this is far more powerful and easier than the classical XPath